# How to return a model in an other one using a query?

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

I have the following database table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "email" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "pet_name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "pet_age"   INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I have the following C# models:

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Pet Pet { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

How could I do a SQLite `SELECT *` query that would return a `User` object, with the right `Pet` infos?

This is what I tried:

```cs
public static User GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
    using var con = new SQLiteConnection(Globals.DbConnectionString);

    return con.QueryFirstOrDefault<User>($"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = @email COLLATE NOCASE", new
    {
        email
    });
}
```

But this wouldn't work with the `Pet` model, obviously it isn't magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with using `dynamic`:

```cs
public static User GetUser(ulong discordId)
{
    using var con = new SQLiteConnection(Globals.DbConnectionString);

    var user = con.QueryFirstOrDefault<dynamic>($"SELECT * FROM {DbTable} WHERE discord_id = @discordId", new
    {
        discordId
    });

    if (user == null) return null;

    return new User
    {
        DiscordId = (ulong)user.discord_id,
        RegistrationTimestamp = (long)user.registration_timestamp,
        Email = (string)user.email,
        Balance = (double)user.balance,
        Profit = new Profit
        {
            Net = (double)user.net_profit,
            ATH = (double)user.ath_profit,
            ATL = (double)user.atl_profit
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You don't need the dynamic stuff. You can get Dapper to map the `Profit`/`Pet` for you. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fields that you return from SQL have to match your Model. You can create concrete object with your return query then parse it to your real objects:

```
public class UserPetQueryResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PetName { get; set; }
    public int PetAge { get; set; }
}



public static User GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
    using var con = new SQLiteConnection(Globals.DbConnectionString);

     UserPetQueryResult  dbResult = con.QueryFirstOrDefault<UserPetQueryResult>($"SELECT id as Id,email as Email,pet_name as PetName,pet_age as PetAge FROM users WHERE email = @email COLLATE NOCASE", new
        {
            email
        });

    return new User() {
            Email = dbResult.Email,
            Pet = new Pet(){
                Name = dbResult.PetName,
                Age = dbResult.PetAge
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: There must be a more elegant solution for sure, or maybe not?

Comment: This is the most common way of doing this. I think this is more elegant solution compared to your answer(which sugguest to use dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple one-to-one mapping like this:

```cs
string sql = "SELECT * FROM {DbTable} WHERE discord_id = @discordId";

using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Globals.DbConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    var foundUser = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<User, Pet, User>(
            sql,
            (user, pet) =>
            {
                user.Pet = pet;
                return user;
            },
            splitOn: "pet_name");
}
```

You tell the query to get a `User` and a `Pet` and return a user. The database column that divides `User` and `Pet` is "pet_name", meaning that all columns to the left of "pet_name" is mapped to user and the columns to the right of "pet_name" (including pet_name) are mapped to pet. It is the up to you to combine the two.